# Extra Backslash Required in First Appended Newline in sed

Tags: sed

While appending some text after a matched pattern, I wanted to add an empty line with a comment to isolate my additions from the rest. However, I have noticed that for the very first `\n`, I need to escape the `\` with an additional `\` (makes it `\\n`) but this is apparently not required for rest of the appended text. **Why is this so?**

An example that I produced on a SUSE 11 server (bash v3.2.57(2) and GNU sed version 4.1.5) is:

```
edwdev@hdpedge1:/edw> sed '/test/a \\nNot a test\nJust Playing' <<< test
test

Not a test
Just Playing
```

If I do not escape the first `\n` (right after the `a` sed command, I get an **n** printed instead of a newline.

```
edwdev@hdpedge1:/edw> sed '/test/a \nNot a test\nJust Playing' <<< test
test
nNot a test
Just Playing
```

Notice that I have intentionally added a space after `a` command so that it doesn't conflict accidentally with alternate syntax.

Same behavior is observed if I replace `\n` with `\t`.Number of spaces after `a` command do not seem to matter; the first backslash needs to be escaped to print the special character even after multiple spaces.

---

Same is the case on another environment, where I originally observed this; a Centos 7 x64 VM, bash version is 4.2.46(2) and sed version is GNU sed 4.2.2

```
sed -i '/\[mysqld\]/a \\n# <<INSERTED MANUALLY>>\ntransaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED\ninnodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT\nmax_connections=550\n# <<END OF MANUAL INSERTIONS >>\n' /etc/my.cnf
```

**Output:**

```
...
[mysqld]

# <<INSERTED MANUALLY>>
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
max_connections=550
# <<END OF MANUAL INSERTIONS >>

...
```

**Output Without Escaping first \n:**

```
[mysqld]
n# <<INSERTED MANUALLY>>
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
max_connections=550
# <<END OF MANUAL INSERTIONS >>
```

Is there any particular reason for this behavior? I am unable to find any details while skimming through the docs ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)), through, admittedly, I haven't read the entire documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly documented behaviour, but then the entire thing is an extension. All three commands that were extended similarly (`a`, `i` and `c`) behave the same way: leading whitespace is ignored, and if the text begins with `\`, then it is discarded. Essentially, it doesn't matter to sed which of these forms are used:

```
i foo
i \foo
i \
foo
```

They're all identical. (I know I used `i` here, but check the the descriptions of `a`, `i` and `c` - it's surreal.)

And [the code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=blob;f=sed/compile.c;h=7081fc966e2295a5da17b1efea27e827dd568271;hb=HEAD#l1121) shows as much:

```
1111         case 'a':
1112         case 'i':
1113         case 'c':
1114           ch = in_nonblank ();
1115 
1116         read_text_to_slash:
1117           if (ch == EOF)
1118             bad_prog (_(EXPECTED_SLASH));
1119 
1120           if (ch == '\\')
1121             ch = inchar ();
```

Answer (score 4):

[The standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html) form of the `a` command in `sed` is

```
a\
text to be appended
```

The `c` and `i` command follow the same format.

If further lines are to be appended, the newline of each has to be escaped:

```
a\
text to\
be appended
```

Standard `sed` does not know to interpret `\n` as newline as GNU `sed` does, so your single line command with a non-GNU `sed` would be written (in `bash`) as

```
sed $'/test/a\\\n\\\nNot a test\\\nJust Playing\n' <<<test
```

Here, we use `$'...'` to make the shell replace each `\n` with an actual newline and `\\` with `\`.

The command could be written as the following without the `$'...'` feature of `bash`:

```
sed '/test/a\
\
Not a test\
Just Playing
' <<<test
```

Both of these commands would work with GNU `sed` too.

GNU `sed` additionally allows the appended text to occur without an intervening newline between it and the preceding `a`, and allows for dropping the `\` completely, **but will interpret the `\` immediately following the `a` command as the backslash in the standard `a\` form of the command** (this is the basic issue in your question). GNU `sed` also adds a newline at the end of the appended text in the script.  So with GNU `sed`, you could write

```
sed '/test/a\ \
Not a test\
Just Playing' <<<test
```

or, using the fact that GNU `sed` knows `\n`,

```
sed '/test/a\\nNot a test\nJust Playing' <<<test
```

Comment: It's also possible to to use multiple expressions to get the same effect as multiple lines. Looks somewhat nicer that way too `sed -e '/test/a\' -e 'Not a test\nJust Playing' <<<test`